# Truncate/round whole number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, decimal, rounding

For a script I'm writing, I need display a number that has been rounded, but not the decimal or anything past it. I've gotten down to rounding it to the third place, but I'm not sure how to go about just dropping the decimal and everything past it, as it doesn't seem like JavaScript has a `substr` function like PHP does.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Rounding and truncating are 2 different operations. Which one are you trying to do?

Comment: `.substring()` is absolutely a function in javascript.

Comment: **THE METHOD IS CALLED `.toFixed()`**

Comment: don't use toFixed. it will round.  e.g.  (999/1000).toFixed(0) -> '1'. As @ryan says says use Math.trunc

Comment: Here's useful JSPerf: https://jsperf.com/different-ways-to-truncate/1

Answer (score 135, accepted):

If you have **a string**, parse it as an integer:

```
var num = '20.536';
var result = parseInt(num, 10);  // 20
```

If you have **a number**, ECMAScript 6 offers `Math.trunc` for completely consistent truncation, already available in Firefox 24+ and Edge:

```
var num = -2147483649.536;
var result = Math.trunc(num);  // -2147483649
```

If you can’t rely on that and will always have a positive number, you can of course just use `Math.floor`:

```
var num = 20.536;
var result = Math.floor(num);  // 20
```

And finally, if you have a number in [−2147483648, 2147483647], you can truncate to 32 bits using any bitwise operator. `| 0` is common, and `>>> 0` can be used to obtain an unsigned 32-bit integer:

```
var num = -20.536;
var result = num | 0;  // -20
```

Comment: Math.floor() will give the wrong result for negative numbers.  Consider mozey's answer below for better alternatives.

Comment: @JonBrooks: Thanks, but I recommended `parseInt` to begin with. Consider mozey’s answer for slow, complex alternatives.

Comment: mozey's `trunc2` is actually the correct option, plus it uses integer comparison rather than string parsing which would make it much faster than `parseInt`, along with always returning the correct result.

Comment: @BlinkyTop: Eric talked about the `substr` function, so my first option talked about strings. I’m well aware of the problems of using `parseInt` on a number (see my comment on mozey’s answer, which is actually mostly wrong).

Comment: Are you sure about `Math.trunc` being supported in IE 11? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) says there is no IE support. I also tried it in IE 11 and got "Object doesn't support property or method 'trunc'".

Comment: @FrankTan: Ah, sorry, I had meant Edge. Luckily, it’s easy to shim.

Answer (score 18):

Travis Pessetto's answer along with mozey's `trunc2` function were the only correct answers, considering how JavaScript represents very small or very large floating point numbers in scientific notation.

For example, `parseInt(-2.2043642353916286e-15)` will not correctly parse that input. Instead of returning `0` it will return `-2`.

This is the correct (and imho the least insane) way to do it:

```
function truncate(number)
{
    return number > 0
         ? Math.floor(number)
         : Math.ceil(number);
}
```

Comment: For me Math.trunc(-2.2043642353916286e-15) returns zero. I have tested it in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Answer (score 14):

I'll add my solution here.  We can use floor when values are above 0 and ceil when they are less than zero:

```
function truncateToInt(x)
{
    if(x > 0)
    {
         return Math.floor(x);
    }
    else
    {
         return Math.ceil(x);
    }
 }
```

Then:

```
y = truncateToInt(2.9999); // results in 2
y = truncateToInt(-3.118); //results in -3
```

**Notice**: This answer was written when `Math.trunc(x)` was fairly new and not supported by a lot of browsers.  Today, modern browsers support `Math.trunc(x)`.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was downvoted. It is the only correct way!

Comment: @BlinkyTop Because `Math.trunc(x)` does exactly that

Comment: @magnap when this question was answered `Math.trunc(x)` was fairly new and not supported by all modern browsers at the time.  For example, it would not work with Microsoft Edge at the time (Edge 12 released in 2015 and onward does support it) and IE even today does not support `Math.trunc(x)`.

Answer (score 10):

Convert the number to a string and throw away everything after the decimal.

```
trunc = function(n) { return Number(String(n).replace(/\..*/, "")) }

trunc(-1.5) === -1

trunc(1.5) === 1
```

**Edit 2013-07-10**

As pointed out by minitech and on second thought the string method does seem a bit excessive. So comparing the various methods listed here and elsewhere:

```
function trunc1(n){ return parseInt(n, 10); }
function trunc2(n){ return n - n % 1; }
function trunc3(n) { return Math[n > 0 ? "floor" : "ceil"](n); }
function trunc4(n) { return Number(String(n).replace(/\..*/, "")); }

function getRandomNumber() { return Math.random() * 10; }

function test(func, desc) {
    var t1, t2;
    var ave = 0;
    for (var k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        t1 = new Date().getTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            window[func](getRandomNumber());
        }
        t2 = new Date().getTime();
        ave += t2 - t1;
    }
    console.info(desc + " => " + (ave / 10));
}

test("trunc1", "parseInt");
test("trunc2", "mod");
test("trunc3", "Math");
test("trunc4", "String");
```

The results, which may vary based on the hardware, are as follows:

```
parseInt => 258.7
mod      => 246.2
Math     => 243.8
String   => 1373.1
```

The Math.floor / ceil method being marginally faster than parseInt and mod. String does perform poorly compared to the other methods.

Comment: `parseInt` and string replacement will return incorrect answers for numbers larger than 999999999999999900000.

Comment: my take-away from this experience: unless performance is a huge issue, just use `parseInt` for simplicity, otherwise implement `trunc3()`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Math.floor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw6w4wz7%28VS.94%29.aspx):

```
var f = 20.536;
var i = Math.floor(f);  // 20
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J4UVV/1/

Comment: If you use a negative number say -20.536 then you will get the wrong result for truncation as it results in -21 http://jsfiddle.net/zL1v5e2k/

Answer (score 1):

**Math.trunc()** function removes all the fractional digits.

For positive number it behaves exactly the same as Math.floor():

```
console.log(Math.trunc(89.13349)); // output is 89
```

For negative numbers it behaves same as Math.ceil():

```
console.log(Math.trunc(-89.13349)); //output is -89
```