# Kendo grid truncate decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to prevent this value from rounding and 2 decimal point only? I tried this but is not working,

```js
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    field: "colTwo",
    format: "{0:n2}",
    editor: amountE
  } ],
  filterable: true,
  dataSource: [ { colTwo: 0.377941} ]
});

function amountE(container, options) {
  $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoNumericTextBox({
    decimal: 1,
    round: false,
    //format: "{0:n2}",
  })
}
```

Comment: What's the expected result for you and what is the result you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to prevent this value from rounding?

Try [This](http://dojo.telerik.com/eHaCeJAk/2)

By entering the format `"{0: n2}"`,
 inside the table, you're asking to round to two decimal places. Change the format to get the original value or different rounds.

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    field: "colTwo",
    format: "{0}"
  } ],
  filterable: true,
  dataSource: [ { colTwo: 0.377941} ]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

> And it is possible to display only 2 decimal point?

In this case, I recommend using templates by truncating the value. At this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149806/truncate-round-whole-number-in-javascript) you can find examples of how to truncate a value on javascript (without rounding). In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172987/how-to-truncate-decimals-in-javascript-without-math-library) instead how to do it without using the Math library.

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    field: "colTwo",
    format: "{0}",
    template: '#= (((colTwo * 100)|0)/100) #'

  } ],
  filterable: true,
  dataSource: [ { colTwo: 0.377941} ]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Dojo [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/eHaCeJAk/10).

Comment: I edited my previous answer to add the resolution to this question. I hope it will be useful to you